# Applescript permissions in Mac OS 12

Tags: applescript, monterey, apple-music, filemaker

My music licensing business uses Filemaker and quite a few Applescripts as part of its day to day operations. For years we have been running everything on OS 10.14 without any issues. We recently updated our OS to 12.1. Many of the Applescripts are now broken. I've spent the better part of the day trying to get one that imports music files into Music (the script used to use iTunes), sets all the tags, and converts them to other file formats and found that many of the steps simply do not trigger seemingly from permissions issues. Changing:

```
set newfile to ("path to file")
```

to

```
set newfile to alias ("path to file")
```

fixed the ability to import the music track in. I also ran:

```
-e 'tell application "Music" to activate'
```

from Terminal to see if that would fix the permission, and and that did fix many of the steps if I run the script from the Script Editor. However, the scripts need to run from Filemaker. So, 1) is there a similar command I can run to allow FileMaker to run the scripts without issue (I tried adding Filemaker to the Privacy Pane - both Accessibility and Full Disk Access - but no luck), and 2) are there "general" best steps when upgrading Applescripts to work with OS 12? Thanks for any help!

Update: In Security & Privacy > Automation, I do also have FileMaker Pro allowed to control Finder and Music.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier and faster running a shell command from within an Applescript using `do shell script`. Set a $variable to

```
"do shell script (\"sudo cp path-to-origfile path-to-newfile\")"
```

and perform this $variable in Filemaker as Applescript.